# Scala Constructors, Named Arguments, and Implicit Getters/Setters

Tags: scala, constructor, getter-setter, coding-style

Is it possible to use named arguments in a Scala constructor, and later on override getters and setters without breaking the constructor interface or making the code extremely ugly?

Take the following bit of scala code

```
class Person( var FirstName: String, var LastName: String )
```

Nice and clean. This would create a simple class called person, which we could use in the following way

```
val john = new Person( FirstName="John", LastName="Doe" )
john.FirstName = "Joe"
println( john.FirstName )
```

Later, we decide we want to add some validation to the FirstName setter. As such, we create a new private local variable and override the getter and setter methods

```
class Person( var _FirstName: String, var _LastName: String ) {

    def FirstName = _FirstName  
    def FirstName_= (value:String) = _FirstName = value

}
```

Still somewhat clean, however in order to do this, we've had to change the constructor argument names, thus breaking the external interface.

The first solution to this problem I came up with was

```
class Person {
    var _FirstName:String = null 
    var LastName:String  = null

    def FirstName = _FirstName  
    def FirstName_= (value:String) = _FirstName = value

    def this( FirstName: String, LastName: String ){
        this()
        this._FirstName = FirstName
        this.LastName = LastName 
    }

}
```

Which is somewhat ugly and inelegant, and removes most of the nice reasons I was using scala in the first place.

Is there a better way of doing this?

tl;dr How to override getters/setters for members defined in the default constructor without making the code ugly or changing the public interface?

Comment: I'm not sure if your example is real or made up for the sake of this discussion, but why'd anyone in their right mind open up the guts of a class to the world using `public var`?

Comment: This was in the early days as I was first learning Scala. Absolutely everything about this question and what I was trying to do was stupid.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're not already using implicit conversions to create the arguments, you can do something like this:

```
def validateName(s: String) = {
  if (s.length>0 && s(0).isUpper) s
  else throw new IllegalArgumentException(s+" is not a name!")
}

object Example {
  private[Example] class ValidatedName(val s: String) { }
  class Person(var firstName: ValidatedName, var lastName: String) { }
  implicit def string2valid(s: String) = new ValidatedName(validateName(s))
  implicit def valid2string(v: ValidatedName) = v.s
}

scala> new Example.Person("Joe","Schmoe")
res17: Example.Person = Example$Person@51887dd5

scala> new Example.Person("ee","cummings")
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: ee is not a name!
```

It's not *binary* compatible, but it is source compatible (again, if the names weren't already relying upon implicit conversions).

Another slightly longer possibility is to create a stealth ancestor:

```
class CheckedPerson(private var first: String, var lastName: String) {
  def firstName = first
  def firstName_=(s: String) { first = validateName(s) }
}
class Person(firstName: String, lastName: String) extends
  CheckedPerson(validateName(firstName),lastName) { }
```

for which I'm not sure about binary compatibility, but will definitely give source compatibility.

Comment: The stealth ancestor method looks like the best way to go here. Still not particularly elegant, but much cleaner than my first attempt. Thanks :)

Comment: can't you just put the validation logic in the primary constructor of  `ValidatedName` instead of a separate function?

Comment: @ErikAllik No; I think that would cause the validation to be run during object construction, but not during setting of the field value. So it would protect against creating “ee cummings”, but you could change the person’s name to “ee cummings” afterwards, which would be bad (given that you want all Person objects to have uppercase names).

Answer (score 10):

Did you consider using an companion object?

```
class Person private (f: String, l: String ) {
   var FirstName = f
   var LastName = l
}

object Person {
   def apply(FirstName:String, LastName:String) = 
       new Person(FirstName, LastName) 
}
```

Comment: Is this binary compatible to the old version?

Comment: @ziggystar, The `Person(FirstName = "foo", LastName = "bar")` syntax would be binary compatible, but `new Person(...)` would no longer work.

Comment: Unfortunately I need to keep the constructor public interface unchanged.

Answer (score 4):

No. There is currently no way to do that, it's currently not the focus of research.

It is one of my major pet peeves I have with the language: There is no sensible way to combine constructor arguments and self-defined getter/setter methods.

If you're not happy with the functionality `class Person( var FirstName: String, var LastName: String )` provides, it basically means "back to Java's verboseness".

Comment: Do you know if there's much acceptance in the community for changes to the syntax? I'd consider jumping in and implementing some changes myself to make getters/setters work a little nicer.

Comment: Afaik you would first have to write up your plans in a "SID" (Scala improvement document) and Mrtin Odersky has to agree on it. :-) Imho I think the chances are very slim that this will be improved.